# The use of Task.Delay to convert synchronous call to async

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have a WPF application that call `PrintDialog.PrintVisual()` in an async event and the first line is of the event is a call to `await Task.Delay(1);` to return the control to the UI (show a busy Indicator animation) while the printing process is done.

I have never seen this use of `Task.Delay` and searching in google I have not found  any code that do something like that, so I'm wondering if it is correct use of the function or if there is a better approach.

(i know this question can be Off Topic but  i don't know a better place to ask, if you consider there is a better place for this question tell me and I'll take it there)

**Edit**

this is the code inside the event:

```
            await Task.Delay(1);
            IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BusyIndicator.Header = "Imprimiendo...";
            var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog())
                printDialog.PrintVisual(PrintCanvas, "Iprimiendo Venta " + _vm.Sell.Id);
            IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            BusyIndicator.Header = "Cargando...";
```

Comment: You'd have to show most of the code, how it's called from the toplevel event. But I guess this isn't converting the core call to async, it just wraps it in some async before/after code.

Comment: the event is attached to a button's click, so is an `async void` onClick event.

Comment: await Task.Delay(1) should be replaced by await Task.Yield()

Comment: @SirRufo the documentation states  "The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher than input and rendering work. For this reason, do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive." :(

Comment: @SirRufo but the result (at least for now) is the same

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
await Task.Delay(1)
```

will make the method async from the point of view of the compiler, but is won't make the operation asynchronous. All it will do is free up the UI thread for 1ms.

To make the operation asynchronous, you can put it into a separate function and start it as a task.

```
private async Task DoPrint()
{
  IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  BusyIndicator.Header = "Imprimiendo...";
  var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
  if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog())
      printDialog.PrintVisual(PrintCanvas, "Iprimiendo Venta " + _vm.Sell.Id);
  IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  BusyIndicator.Header = "Cargando...";
}

private void EventHandler()
{ 
  await DoPrint() ;
}
```

or you could do the same using a lambda function

```
private void EventHandler()
{ 
  await Task.Run ( () => 
  {
    IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    BusyIndicator.Header = "Imprimiendo...";
    var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog())
        printDialog.PrintVisual(PrintCanvas, "Iprimiendo Venta " + _vm.Sell.Id);
    IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    BusyIndicator.Header = "Cargando...";
  });
}
```

However, in your case, you probably only want some of it to be asynchronous.

My guess it that it is only call to pringDialog.PrintVisual() which needs to be asynchronous, so it would be sufficient to start this in a task.

```
private void EventHandler()
{ 
  IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  BusyIndicator.Header = "Imprimiendo...";
  var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
  if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog())
  {
      await Task.Run ( () => printDialog.PrintVisual(PrintCanvas, "Iprimiendo Venta " + _vm.Sell.Id) ) ;
  }    
  IsBusy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  BusyIndicator.Header = "Cargando...";
}
```

Comment: your first example is how the code look right now (but with Task.Delay or Task.Yield) since as the documentation says if inside the async method there is no await the method is executed synchronously, also the event handler has to be async void or it will give compilation error.

your last example is how I'm refactoring it

Comment: also to tell you how the program behaves with the code in your first example, the ui is frozen while the printDialog is beign created, but after it is shown the UI is responsive again while you interact with the dialog and then frozen again while doing the actual printing